# pdfjs - What is a fake worker? How to solve it

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I'm trying to render a PDF with PDFJS, but get a warning `Setting up fake worker`. What does it mean in practice?

console

```
Warning: Setting up fake worker.
```

code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/3.0.279/pdf.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/3.0.279/pdf.worker.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="pdf"></canvas>
    </body>
    <script>
'use strict';

let pdfPath = 'https://path-to-pdf.pdf';
pdfjsLib.getDocument(pdfPath).promise.then(pdf=>{
    pdf.getPage(1).then(page=>{
        const viewport = page.getViewport({scale: 1}), canvas = document.getElementById('pdf'), context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;
        const renderContext = {
            canvasContext: context,
            viewport: viewport
        };
        page.render(renderContext);
    });
}).then(_=>{
    
}, err=>{
    console.error('Error: '+err);
});
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Setting up viewport may be key: value based.  In my travels I've used viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale, });

Comment: @TuxedoedCastle thanks.. now it works.. But can you help with the warning? :)

Comment: that seems to be coming from within pdf.js.  its just a warning, not an error to worry about and shouldnt be affecting your ability to load the pdf.  is your pdf loading now?

Comment: @TuxedoedCastle no the PDF is loading fine. But just wanted to know if it affected some performance?

Comment: Oh no it doesnt affect performance that you could ever notice. for the clearest explanation of what they mean in practice you may want to search and read up on 'service workers'.  The run asynchronously behind the scenes so dont affect you page load times or anything.

Comment: Loading a PDF without a pdfjs worker _does_ definitely affect the performance a lot! It blocks the whole "main thread" until the PDF is loaded. E.g. try loading a large PDF file while an animation is playing, or try clicking a button while the large PDF is loading.

Answer (score 0):

The [pdfjs](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) "fake worker" behaves in the same way as the "real" worker does, but it runs in the main thread instead of a web worker.

Always use a real worker, ignoring this warning will make the website slow.

### The real worker

pdfjs expects you to provide the location of the `pdf.worker.js` file *(or `pdf.worker.min.js`)*, which comes with the pdfjs package *(currently under `/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js`)*.

If the worker is correctly provided and its location specified, then pdfjs will create a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) which will render PDF files "in the background", i.e. not blocking the main thread. I.e. the website stays responsive while the PDF is created.

### The fake worker

If you don't set the pdf-worker, or the pdf-worker can not be found in the location that you specified, then pdfjs doesn't create a web worker, but [something that looks exactly like the web worker](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js#L2302) but runs in the main thread.

As this affects the performance of the website a lot *(and most often is a mistake, not intentional)*, pdfjs prints a warning in the console `Setting up fake worker`.

### Solutions

Generally:

1. The pdf worker file `pdf.worker.js` *(or `pdf.worker.min.js`)* must be available,
2. pdfjs must know where the pdf worker file is

To solve the problem there are different ways, also depending on the environment and framework. Here are some hints:

- make sure the file `pdf.worker.js` is reachable for your script *(e.g. check by typing `http://localhost:3000/pdf.worker.js` in the browsers address bar)*. One option is to copy the file `pdf.worker.js` into a folder that can be reached by the browser (aka. "public folder").
- set the workerSrc to the url of the `pdf.worker.js` file, like `pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = './pdf.worker.min.js'`
- make sure the version of `pdfjs` and `pdf.worker.js` are the same
- in case of server side rendering, make sure the worker file is set in the browser, not on the server